# Managing the program version with Jenkins, build number and svn revision

Tags: c++, svn, jenkins, versioning

We are currently using Jenkins for CI. 
I chose Jenkins as we are deploying many programs on many different platforms (linux, windows, embedded systems.). This helps us a lot but we have difficulties to manage program version numbers correctly.
Some developpers use their own notations and I wish to normalize everything a bit...

I consider the two fundamentals version numbers:

```
#define MAJOR  1
#define MINOR  0
```

I think about adding two additional numbers, such as:

```
#define BUILD_NUMBER 66
#define SVN_REVISION 77
```

But I'm facing issues:

Firstly, for example the program FooServer depends of X libraries (that we developed) and each lib trunk might have a different SVN Revision.
So, if should include a SVN revision number, would it be more relevant to use the FooServer revision number or maybe the highest SVN revision number of the project SVN urls (program + dependencies) ?

Secondly, I think about using Jenkins BuildNumber variable to link a program with an (archived) job in Jenkins. I just wonder if it's actually relevant enough.

In addition, I need to add an information in the version string to distinguish the nighty snapshot builds (not developers builds) and the release being deployed in production.
Maybe by adding an additional info ?

Finally, these `#define` would of course be stored in a cpp header file generated at Build time and will never be commited to the repo. In order to prevent developpers from bulding release from their workstations (we experienced too many problems that way). 
On the SVN repo, the header file would remain at a development stage:

```
#define MAJOR 1
#define MINOR 0
#define BUILD_NUMBER X
#define SVN_REVISION dev
```

Well, your experience is welcome. The developers of our team do not want too much constraints but on the other hands I need to establish some notations rules for more robustness.

Comment: Concerning your first question: Does all program and lib code reside in the same repository?

Comment: Most of them, yes. There are some exceptions but we're currently in the process of migrating them in the same repo.

Comment: If all code is in the same repository, the highest revision number should be sufficient. At least it was sufficient for me in the last years :-)

Answer (score 1):

If all the code is in one SVN repo, it works well just using the youngest revision number. It makes sense actually, if some library changes and triggers a new build of your project, the new build should not have the same rev as the old one, because it is not the same.

I haven't found much use for including build number in compilation. Using the build date can provide better build identification. There is a plugin called [ZenTimestamp Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ZenTimestamp+Plugin) which gives you a BUILD_TIMESTAMP variable to use in scripts with a date format of your choosing.

Build number might still be useful for you if you're doing things like archiving PDBs for each build on the job itself. I store them elsewhere, named by SVN revision, so it's not really necessary.

Your final step is sensible. We (the company I work for) do the same, except there isn't even a hardcoded one in SVN.

I don't know how you're handling cross platform projects, but we use CMake for project generation, so we just have that generate a header file at configure time containing the correct values (`#define REVISION dev`, etc). That way, a Jenkins build step can generate a CMake preload config file using the contents of the SVN_REVISION and BUILD_TIMESTAMP variables. It is easy enough to add additional information at this stage, such as whether it's a production build or a nightly.